# datatables Load data exception

Tags: java, datatables

I've got the JSON data behind the scenes, that's it

```
[{"aid":100000,"name":"JYCM201609010250","rtsp":"947|100000|3750","statuz":"1","updateTime":"2017-05-31"},{"aid":100001,"name":"gui","rtsp":"947|100000|3750","statuz":"0","updateTime":"2017-05-31"}]
```

Background and foreground code are as follows

```
@Autowired
private MediaImpl media;
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/media",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Media> MediaAll(){
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    return media.findAll();
}
```

JS code is as follows

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_id_example').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/media",
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function (json) {
               console.log(json)
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": 'aid'

            },
            {
                "data": 'name'

            },
            {
                "data": 'rtsp'

            },
            {
                "data": 'statuz'

            },
            {
                "data": 'updateTime'

            }
        ]
    });
});
```

html code is as follows
 [image]

The console code

```
VM178:10 (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {aid: 100000, name: "JYCM201609010250", rtsp: "947|100000|3750", statuz: "1", updateTime: "2017-05-31"}1: {aid: 100001, name: "gui", rtsp: "947|100000|3750", statuz: "0", updateTime: "2017-05-31"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

**There is no error in the front-end console, and no errors in the back end.But the data is not available**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The first is that datatables expects data in a data element of the json response, such as:

```
{
    data: [{"aid":100000,"name":"JYCM201609010250","rtsp":"947|100000|3750","statuz":"1","updateTime":"2017-05-31"},{"aid":100001,"name":"gui","rtsp":"947|100000|3750","statuz":"0","updateTime":"2017-05-31"}]
}
```

You should be able to use `ajaxSrc: ""` on your DataTable settings.

The second problem is with your ajax settings. DataTables states you can not supply the success callback in the ajax settings as it uses this internally.

Documentation on both of these issues:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Assuming you are using DataTables 1.10.x